# Pass php variable to javascript (variable in javascript is undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, variables

I'm trying to pass php variables to js like:

```
    function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts()
    {
       if (is_checkout()) {
            wp_enqueue_script('script-to-pass', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/chkt-script.js', ['jquery'], $GLOBALS['dynamic_version'], '');
       }

    }
    add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts');


   $chktValStrings = array(
     'phoneEmpty'    => __( 'Phone empty', 'flatsome' ),
     'phoneFormat'   => __( 'Phone format', 'flatsome' ),
  );


 wp_add_inline_script( 'script-to-pass', 'var php_vars = ' . wp_json_encode( $chktValStrings ), 'before' );

//this also didn't work
//wp_localize_script( 'script-to-pass', 'php_vars', $chktValStrings);
```

and then call in js:

```
    (function ($) {

      console.log(php_vars.phoneEmpty)
      console.log(php_vars.phoneFormat)

    }(jQuery))
```

I also tryed with:

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

      console.log(php_vars.phoneEmpty)
      console.log(php_vars.phoneFormat)
     });
```

And in both scenarios php_vars is undefined. Script is loading ok also other code in this script works like it should.

Dynamic version in enqueue_script is version which is used on all page when we make changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wp_add_inline_script` function should be called within the `wp_print_scripts` hook. move it into `wpdocs_theme_name_scripts` function.

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts()
{
    if (!is_checkout()) {
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_script('script-to-pass', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/chkt-script.js', ['jquery'], $GLOBALS['dynamic_version'], '');
    $chktValStrings = array(
        'phoneEmpty'    => __('Phone empty', 'flatsome'),
        'phoneFormat'   => __('Phone format', 'flatsome'),
    );


    wp_add_inline_script('script-to-pass', 'var php_vars = ' . wp_json_encode($chktValStrings), 'before');

    //this also should work
    //wp_localize_script( 'script-to-pass', 'php_vars', $chktValStrings);
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts');
```